# Binary compiled in prestage doesn't work in scratch container

Tags: docker, netcat

I have a multi-stage Dockerfile that compiles netcat to use it in a scratch image later. (This has no particular use, but to test how this is done.)

```
FROM alpine:latest AS build
RUN wget -q -O /root/netcat.tar.bz2 https://vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net/project/netcat/netcat/0.7.1/netcat-0.7.1.tar.bz2 && \
apk --no-cache add --update gcc g++ make
WORKDIR /root/
RUN tar xvjf /root/netcat.tar.bz2
WORKDIR /root/netcat-0.7.1/
RUN ./configure && make && make install

FROM scratch # When using alpine here it works
WORKDIR /bin/
COPY --from=build /usr/local/bin/netcat /bin/netcat
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/netcat"]
```

When running this image I get the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

The file is there because it works when using alpine as second image. When using busybox, I could use /bin/sh as entrypoint, but when executing netcat from that shell, it wouldn't work either.

Do I have some problem of different architectures here? I don't know what is happening...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the `scratch` base image is **an explicitly empty image**. It has no shared object, it has no runtime libraries.

If you want to put your executable binary into the `scratch` base image, make sure you compile your binary with `-static` flags. Apparently the `netcat` built from the first step has something to depend on:

```
$ ldd netcat
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe168f1000)
libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => not found
```

Comment: The `--static` flag didn't change much for me. Moving `libc.musl-x86_64.so.1` over helped and made it work. Thanks!